# TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not function

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I'd just like to preface this by saying that I have indeed looked up this issue, but everyone who seems to have had a similar issue has found a solution that doesn't work for me. I'm using python 3.4.3 64 bit and pygame 1.9.2a and getting the error stated in the title. My code looks like this at the moment:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (200,0,0)
bright_red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,200,0)
bright_green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,200)
bright_blue = (0,0,255)

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Le jeux')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

thatonething = pygame.image.load('thatonething.png')

def thatonething(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(thatonething,(x,y))

x = (display_width * 0.45)
y = (display_height * 0.8)

crashed = False

while not crashed:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True
        print(event) 

    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    thatonething(x,y)
    pygame.display.update() 
    clock.tick(30) 

pygame.quit() 
quit()
```

Running it gives me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Windows 8/Desktop/Scripts/New folder/Main.py", line 39, in <module>
    thatonething(x,y)
  File "C:/Users/Windows 8/Desktop/Scripts/New folder/Main.py", line 24, in thatonething
    gameDisplay.blit(thatonething,(x,y))
TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not function
```

Thanks in advance, and sorry if this sounds like a stupid question.

Edit: This has now been solved thanks to Brian. For anyone with a similar issue who might see this later, the corrected version looks like this:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (200,0,0)
bright_red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,200,0)
bright_green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,200)
bright_blue = (0,0,255)

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Le jeux')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

thatonething = pygame.image.load('thatonething.png')

def somefunction(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(thatonething,(x,y))

x = (display_width * 0.45)
y = (display_height * 0.8)

crashed = False

while not crashed:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True
        print(event) #This creates a log of the events that pygame has been handling.

    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    somefunction(x,y)
    pygame.display.update() #Updates everything "pygame.display.flip()" updates just one thing
    clock.tick(30) #This defines the refresh rate i.e. 30 in brackets gives 30 fps

pygame.quit() #Closes the game (with the next line)
quit()
```

The key difference is that 'thatonething' is no longer the name of the function.

Comment: [![Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfKfD.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfKfD.png) In my case , i had written twice a class in my program, passing different values i didn't realize, when i deleted one of them, everything was perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a function:

```
def thatonething(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(thatonething,(x,y))
```

When you put `gameDisplay.blit(thatonething,(x,y))`, it's interpreting the params as 1: `thatonething`, 2: `(x,y)`.

You probably meant to put something else as the input to `gameDisplay.blit` because, even if you remove the comma, you'll have an infinite recursion.

I'm not sure what this function is doing, but you may want to consider redesigning it.

Comment: I recently started looking through [this pygame guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZFo4mtLJEWs) and it seemed to work for him (skip to 18:48 for when he runs it properly). In my head, that layout seems logical, and I can't think of what I'd replace it with.

Comment: Your problem is you reuse the name `thatonething`, consider using different names for the function and the variable (the image). This would solve the problem.

Comment: You're right. I changed the name of the function to "somefunction" and it ran properly. Thank you very much.